# Skipping files in Resharper has no effect

Tags: visual-studio-2013, resharper

I'm editing PHP-Files with Visual Studio. I have ReSharper 8.0.2 Full installed. When I edit PHP-Files ReSharper will inject strange spaces and tabs. So I went to the options and added "*.php" in the items to skip:

[image]

But this doesn't seem to work. There are still injected spaces and tabs. When I suspend ReSharper completely, this behavior stops. What am I doing wrong?

**Edit:** I posted this in [JetBrains YouTrack](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-397429).

Comment: Note that this dialog is about analyzing files. Are you analyzing the .php files when the characters are inserted?

Comment: @JohnSaunders I just recognized that in most scenarios switching of analysing should prevent ReSharper from doing anything: I'm confused on this dialog too, but normally it just works the way I want.

Answer (score 1):

ReSharper shouldn't be inserting spaces or tabs at all - I'd recommend reporting this as a bug, adding a repro if you can: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com

Comment: I'll try that und come back with the result. Thx.